# Splitting by the string "malloc" isn't working and returns a different split

Tags: c, split, c-strings, strtok, strstr

```
char str[2500] ="int *x = malloc(sizeof(int));";
    const char s[9] = "malloc";
    char *token = strtok(str, s);

    while( token != NULL ) {
      printf("%s\n", token );
    
      token = strtok(NULL, s);
    }
```

Output:

```
int *x = 
(size
f(int));
```

I want it to return:

```
int *x = 
(sizeof(int));
```

but oddly it refuses to do that and I can't seem to figure out why it's doing that.

edit: I realized that the size is too small, but still has a problem.

Comment: Yeah, I tried modifying that, still comes out weird

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help should generally provide a [mre] of the problem, which includes a function `main` and all `#include` directives. That way, it is easier for other people to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second parameter of the function strtok means that any character present in the string can be used as a terminating character.

So this substring

```
(sizeof(int))
```

is terminated as soon as the character 'o' present in the string "malloc" is found.

What you need to use is the standard C string function `strstr`. It will find the sub-string "mallpc" in the source string and you will be able to output the sub-strings before "malloc" and after it.

For example

```
char str[2500] ="int *x = malloc(sizeof(int));";
    const char s[9] = "malloc";
    char *p = strstr(str, s);

    if ( p != NULL )
    {
        printf( "%.*s\n", ( int )( p - str ), str );
        if ( p[strlen( s )] != '\0' ) puts( p );
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

The second parameter to `strtok` is a list of characters which serve as delimiters.  It is *not* a complete string used as a delimiter.  So what you actually have is the characters `'m'`, `'a'`, `'l'`, `'o'`, and `'c'` as delimiters, so anyplace one of those characters appears splits the string.

What you want instead is to use `strstr` to search for a substring.  Then you can use that to copy from the start of `str` to the start of the substring, then copy again from the end of the substring to the end of `str`.

Comment: so how would I go around that?

Comment: Use `strstr`...

Comment: but strstr would only find the string would it not?

Comment: Yes. Then you will have to do some extra work "manually".